# Interpolate between two dynamic days

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

We have a file that is updated every week and its structure is as follows:

```
      ID            Code    Days  Yield
KZW1KM093436    NTK273_1343 4    2.1781
KZW1KD913708    NTK091_1370 11   2.1683
KZK1KY011222    MKM012_0122 17   2.1602
KZW1KM063603    NTK182_1360 32   2.1419
KZW1KM093477    NTK273_1347 32   2.1419
KZW1KD913740    NTK091_1374 39   2.1342
KZW1KM063629    NTK182_1362 46   2.1269
KZW1KM093501    NTK273_1350 53   2.1202
```

I have the following static data points (Days) for which I need `Yields` on a weekly basis:

```
28
91
182
273
364
730
1825
2555
3640
```

When the file gets updated, the structure of the data also changes (sorted by `Days`). There are several possible scenarios:

- If the value in `Days` column of the data is equal to any of the
  values in my `Static` data, then I'd like to take the corresponding
  value from `Yield` column.
- Otherwise, I'd like to take the closest upper and lower values from
  `Days` and get interpolated `Yield` (eg. for my static `28` days in
  this particular case I'd have to use these two rows: `KZK1KY011222 MKM012_0122 17   2.1602` and `KZW1KM063603 NTK182_1360 32  2.1419`).
- If there are no beginning or ending values, which mostly applicable
  to `28` and `3640`, then I want to take the `Yield` from the closest
  `Days`.

I was thinking about doing it in Excel/VBA, but would also like to see R solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Expected output for `Yield` is calculated according to this formula:

[image]

So in this case for `28` Days I'd have `Yield` `(28 - 17)*(2.1419-2.1602)/(32-17)+2.1602 = 2.1468`

Comment: Could you please include the expected yield vector at static date points

Comment: @hNu, edited my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 A=read.table(text="ID            Code    Days  Yield
                KZW1KM093436    NTK273_1343 4   2.1781
                KZW1KD913708    NTK091_1370 11  2.1683
                KZK1KY011222    MKM012_0122 17  2.1602
                KZW1KM063603    NTK182_1360 32  2.1419
                KZW1KM093477    NTK273_1347 32  2.1419
                KZW1KD913740    NTK091_1374 39  2.1342
                KZW1KM063629    NTK182_1362 46  2.1269
                KZW1KM093501    NTK273_1350 53  2.1202",header=T)

 k=c(28L, 91L, 182L, 273L, 364L, 730L, 1825L, 2555L, 3640L)
```

Now first find the interval where the value to be predicted lies

```
 funfun=function(x){
             if(x%in%A$Days)return(A[A$Days==x,3:4])
             v=findInterval(x,A$Days);na.omit(A[c(v,v+1),3:4])}
```

eg:

```
 funfun(28)
  Days  Yield
3   17 2.1602
4   32 2.1419
funfun(34)
  Days  Yield
5   32 2.1419
6   39 2.1342
funfun(4)
  Days  Yield
1    4 2.1781
funfun(0)
  Days  Yield
1    4 2.1781
funfun(345)
  Days  Yield
8   53 2.1202
 funfun(11)
  Days  Yield
2   11 2.1683
```

Next we write a function that computes the predicted value:

```
 funfun1=function(i){
   s=funfun(i)
   if(nrow(s)==1)return(s$Yield)
   (i-s$Days[1])*Reduce("/",rev(sapply(s,diff)))+s$Yield[1]
 }

sapply(k,funfun1)
[1] 2.14678 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020
```

Most of the values given in K lie outside the range of the days we have thus only taking the last value. What if we had different values? say:

```
  k=c(4,11,17,18,20,33,48,50)
  sapply(k,funfun1)
  [1] 2.178100 2.168300 2.160200 2.158980 2.156540 2.140800 2.124986 2.123071
```

We see for those values already in the data, we get their yields. Those above the data, we obtain the last yield in the data and those in between we estimate as required.

Hope this will help

Comment: thank you. I didn't get the first output of yours --`2.14678 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020 2.12020`. Why all these values except for the first one are the same?

Comment: I understood that if there are no end days, then you take the closest. And from the table, we see that the last day is 53, so all the days greater than 53 will take the value of 53.. That is how I understood your bullet point 3. And if a day is less than 4, it will take the yield value of 4. Or maybe I did not understand your point on this. You can elaborate further on your point no.3.That is the if statement in the `funfun1` function

Comment: Also you say you get different results. please tofurther clarify your problem, would you mind showing the expected results? so that one is able to know what he/she is aiming at. Thank you